# Cocos2d - First CCAction does not show change

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

I have two CCMoveTo's that run in the onEnterTransitionDidFinish method, used to move sprites. Both are correctly defined, and both work, but only whichever is called second actually shows a visual change. I have NSLoged the positions of the sprites after the call, and the new position is correct, but the position on screen is not.

Is there some call to an updater that I need to make in order for it to recognize the first call?

For clarification:

```
CCMoveBy *moveDown = [CCMoveBy actionWithDuration:0.6f position:ccp(0, -200)];

[backMenu runAction:moveDown]; // Does not show correct position or move animation visually
[menuArm runAction:moveDown]; // Shows correct move animation
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can't reuse the same action 2 time

```
 [backMenu runAction:[moveDown copy]];
 [menuArm runAction:moveDown];
```

a CCAction can be copied, so each time you use the same action you can just copy it.

Comment: In retrospect, that makes a lot of sense - should've noticed it. Thanks!